# Deleting a document using ContentService API doesn't refresh cache

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In Umbraco 7, I used `ContentService` API to insert, update or delete documents. After inserting or updating a document, the correct content shows immediately, but after deleting, removed data can be viewed because of the cache. To clear cache, I delete `DistCache` folder's data from `App_data`.

How can I refresh the cache programmatically?

**Here is my code:**

```
public string DeleteStudent(int studentID)
{
    IContentService service = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
    if (studentID != 0)
    {
        IContent student = service.GetById(studentID);

        if (student != null && student.ContentType.Alias == "dtStudent")
        {
            service.Delete(student);
            return "Done!";
        }
    }
    return "Error!";
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off calling `service.MoveToRecycleBin` - this method will first unpublish the content then move it to the recycle bin. I believe deleting simply deletes it straight from the database.

Comment: Thank you @Harvey, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As @Harvey said in the comment, using `service.MoveToRecycleBin` works
>   fine. That method will unpublish the content, then move it to the
>   recycle bin.

**Final code:**

```
public string DeleteStudent(int studentID)
{
    IContentService service = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
    if (studentID != 0)
    {
        IContent student = service.GetById(studentID);

        if (student != null && student.ContentType.Alias == "dtStudent")
        {
            service.MoveToRecycleBin(student);
            return "Done!";
        }
    }
    return "Error!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you shouldn't have to update the cache manually after a delete (you can check the log file for possible errors)

If you want to do a manual refresh, you can do so by calling the following method

```
umbraco.library.RefreshContent();
```

Note: In an Umbraco instance with many nodes the method is very slow

Comment: It's legacy library, you shouldn't use it. @Ali Try to unpublish element first and then delete it. I can't test it right now, but unpublish event should fire all the cache refreshers to remove this item from published content cache.

Comment: Thank you @Mark. I will check the log.

Comment: Thank you @MarcinZajkowski. I will test that.

Comment: I believe the updated method can be found on the ContentService: `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.RePublishAll();` [source](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/e0025db56d52b770d2b3aedbd48a3b804fd15ef0/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/ContentService.cs#L1012)

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear the cache in the Umbraco back office if you right click on the ellipses by the Content tab and then click "Republish entire site". This is technically not a programmatic way but it's quick/easy and does the job!

```
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIUOh.jpg
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a good way because republishing of the entire site does not affect on DistCache folder of the website app_data.